# How to speed up Test-Driven Development in Visual Studio

Tags: tdd, mstest

Unlike many questions on this topic, this is *not* about speeding up the nature of my tests. I'm referring to pure unit tests which are already fast (< 0.5 sec), but for which the surrounding tooling (Visual Studio 2019's test framework) is painfully slow. I want fast TDD cycles.

Scenario: I'm exercising some simple code in a class library (.NET Framework 4.7.2) with a unit test project (also NF 4.7.2, using the latest (v2.1.2) nuget packages for MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestFramework). In my whole solution I have 2083 tests.

Without changing any code in the code under test, then making a trivial change in the test code and hitting CTRL-R, T (run single test), the whole duration from start to finish is 18 seconds. Here's the breakdown:

3.5 sec build time
0.5 sec test execution time
18  sec total time
which leaves 14 seconds where Test Explorer is just spinning its tires.

I understand the virtues of the whole "red-green-refactor" style of development, but with 18 seconds of dead time every time I make a tiny change and want to test it, I find that it's a productivity killer; can't get into a good grove.

Any ideas how to eliminate that 14 seconds test framework time?

**Edit**

The console approach looks promising (fast execution), but it is more cumbersome (separate windows, copying'n'pasting long file paths, separate build step, etc). If someone could describe how they achieve really fast, effortless TDD cycles with .NET, that would be appreciated.

**Edit 2**

I discovered the `TestDriven.NET` VS extension, which is incredibly fast (completes almost instantly). However, it seems buggy or incomplete (for example, doesn't respect the `[ExpectedException]` attribute). The interesting thing is that on the [project website](https://testdriven.net/quickstart.aspx) it states

> The tests are launched by a test execution engine running as an external process. This test process is kept alive in order to improve execution times on subsequent runs

I wonder if there's a simple way to instruct vanilla VS to keep its test process alive, and if that would achieve the same speeds.

Comment: Use terminal. It is faster and let you run tests in paralle/specific test suites.

Comment: You're right--by using VSTest.Console.exe it shaved off 10 seconds. However, it seems to be quite a bit more complicated of a solution than simply hitting CTRL-R, T. If only there was a way to achieve the speed of console execution, but with the convenience of the IDE.

Comment: TestDriven.NET is great, but unfortunately doesn't work with .NET Core. The VS test runner is awful, but consider upvoting and/or commenting on [this suggestion for improvements](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/701822/test-explorer-better-support-for-tdd-workflow.html).